# How to add an audiotrack in video.js?

Tags: javascript, video.js

in the examples of video.js I've found this:

```
var track = new videojs.AudioTrack({
  id: 'my-spanish-audio-track',
  kind: 'translation',
  label: 'Spanish',
  language: 'es'
});
```

my question is how it is added if there are no `src` attribute, from where does it get the track itself? I mean the source itself like `mp3` or `wav` file

from the docs: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/audio-tracks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audio src under the `<audio controls>` then `<source>` tag. You should define here or create dynamically this elements.

You can download example sounds [here.](http://www.bigsoundbank.com/sound-0897-bell.html)

```js
var player = videojs('my-player');

// Create a track object.
var track = new videojs.AudioTrack({
  id: 'my-spanish-audio-track',
  kind: 'translation',
  label: 'Spanish',
  language: 'es'
});

// Add the track to the player's audio track list.
player.audioTracks().addTrack(track);
```

```html
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.15/video.js"></script>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.15/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<audio id="my-player" class="video-js" controls>
  <source id="my-spanish-audio-track" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Dynamically;

```js
var myAudio=document.createElement("audio");
myAudio.id="my-player";
myAudio.className="video-js";
myAudio.setAttribute("controls",true);
var mySource1=document.createElement("source");
mySource1.id="my-spanish-audio-track";
mySource1.src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg";
mySource1.type="audio/ogg";

myAudio.appendChild(mySource1);
document.body.appendChild(myAudio);

var player = videojs('my-player');

// Create a track object.
var track = new videojs.AudioTrack({
  id: 'my-spanish-audio-track',
  kind: 'translation',
  label: 'Spanish',
  language: 'es'
});

// Add the track to the player's audio track list.
player.audioTracks().addTrack(track);
```

```html
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.15/video.js"></script>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.15/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add audio tracks through HTML like you can with text tracks. They must be added programmatically. Video.js only stores track representations. Switching audio tracks for playback is not handled by Video.js and must be handled elsewhere - for example, videojs-contrib-hls handles switching audio tracks to support track selection through the UI.

Reference: https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-audio-tracks.html